# Play video in UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video

There is so much stuff in Stackoverflow about playing videos in cell, that every person may feel confused, especially that most of question are not solved and it looks like that every developer gives up.

So I wanted to create new question where there will be up-to-date answers.

**Objective:**

Play video in UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell when user taps cell (yes, this is simplified version, this is not about autplay).

**Solution:**

- I think everyone agrees that we should use `AVPlayer` instead of deprecated `MPMoviePlayerController`.
- Cell should have layer where AVPlayer can be assigned, so in my code while creating cell I added this code:

**VideoCell.swift**

```
let layer = AVPlayerLayer()
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

- Now when cell is tapped I'm using this code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
cell.playerLayer.player = player
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(asset: asset))
player.play()
```

Where player is global instance of `AVPlayer` and asset is `AVAsset` initialized with video URL.

It would work fine, but `AVPlayer` needs time to download info and buffer some part of video, and what user gets is delay. So we can think about one solution, which is downloading video first and playing it locally when users taps in cell.

**Question:** 
Is it really good approach to downloading every video in data source and then playing it locally? When should we remove it from device? Facebook and Instagram looks like they download only part of the video first, is there any who can share own experience?

Objective-C code will be appreciated too.

Comment: How are your video assets set up? If you provide HLS then you should get a better streaming experience as opposed to a single video asset

Comment: Just mp4 on server, urls for videos are provided when data is loaded.

Comment: Are you able to change to HLS? https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: Unfortunatelly no.

Comment: @ThirdMartian any updates?

Comment: I will create Github repository with my solution. The trick is to download video first or playing and downloading in the same time.